# Remove directory in hierarchy while preserving status in git

Tags: git, move

I have a repository like

```
  /file1
  /file2
  /dir_a/file3
  /dir_a/file4
  ...
```

how can I remove `dir_a` and move all its content one directory up (in this case to `/`) while keeping the status of all files (untracked, changed but not staged), which may be contained in `/` but also in `dir_a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git-mv` should be able to handle this. Use `git mv -k dir_a/* .`, and the staged/unstaged status will be preserved. This will not move untracked files, so use `mv dir_a/* .` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
# shelving unstaged stuff
git stash
# moving content from /dir_a to /
# that should suffice as git doesn't track directories but only files
git status -uno -s | grep "src_dir" | awk '{print "-n " $2 " dest_dir"}' | xargs -n3 git mv -f
# than move what remains in source dir manually:
mv src_dir/* dest_dir
# resurrect unstaged changes
git stash pop
```

Second line could be better but it worked for me.